# Python unit test patching class with a wrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

So I have a class like below

```
class A(Parent):
  def __init__(self):
  self.instance = B(...args)
```

In my tests whenever, B(...args) is called, I want it to make a call to class `TestA` I define in my tests

```
class TestA(A, HelperClass):
   pass
```

Any way to achieve this?
I know dependencies should be mocked out in unit tests, but this is what I have to deal with.

Comment: You're describing the most basic usage of `mock.patch`. Have you tried reading the docs for that?

Comment: In your setUp method: 1. capture current object definition from module namespace, 2. reassign named var in module your custom value. In your tearDown method: reassign the original definition.

Comment: @wim I have read the doc. It doesn't seem to work(all params new and new_callable). If you think I am misunderstanding it, give an example

Comment: @skullgoblet1089 Any clean way to do it. ex using patch or something else?

Comment: @coderhacker consider using the unittest.TestCase class's setUpClass and tearDownClass methods? https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass. You can probably get by writing only two class methods this way.